# Strange horizontal lines when adding components to container

Tags: layout, codenameone

When adding a series of containers in code to containers defined in the GUI builder, evenly spaced horizontal lines appear across the width of the screen, not relating to any borders of components.

[image: app screenshot with horizontal lines behind components]

Here's my code:

```
public Container[] renderArticles(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> articles){
        Container[] artArray = new Container[articles.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < articles.size(); i++) {
            final HashMap<String, Object> art = articles.get(i);
            Container artCon = mStateMachine.createContainer(mStateMachine.res, "DocArticleItem");
            ActionListener listen = new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    mStateMachine.currentArticleId = (String) art.get("id");
                    mStateMachine.showForm("Article", null);
                }
            };
            Button artPic = mStateMachine.findArticlePic(artCon);
            artPic.addActionListener(listen);
            artPic.setIcon(mStateMachine.makeImageFromRaw((String)art.get("picture_data")));
            SpanButton caption = (SpanButton)mStateMachine.findArticleTitle(artCon);
            caption.setText((String) art.get("title"));
            caption.addActionListener(listen);
            artArray[i] = artCon;
        }
        return artArray;
    }

public Container[] renderTips(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> tips){
        Container[] contArray = new Container[tips.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < tips.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> tip = tips.get(i);
            Container tipCont = mStateMachine.createContainer(mStateMachine.res, "DocTipItem");
            SpanLabel tipTitle = mStateMachine.findDocTipTitle(tipCont);
            tipTitle.setText((String)tip.get("title"));
            SpanLabel tipText = mStateMachine.findDocTipText(tipCont);
            tipText.setText((String)tip.get("info"));
            contArray[i] = tipCont;
        }

        // remove divider from last tip
        Container last = contArray[contArray.length - 1];
        Container line = (Container)last.getComponentAt(last.getComponentCount() - 1);
        last.removeComponent(line);

        return contArray;
    }

final HashMap<String, Object> map = mStateMachine.expertCardInfo;

// populate tips
if (map.containsKey("tips")){
    tipContainers = renderTips((ArrayList) map.get("tips"));
}else{
     f.removeComponent(mStateMachine.findExpertTipsHeader(f));
     f.removeComponent(mStateMachine.findExpertTipsContainer(f));
}

// populate articles
if (map.containsKey("articles")) {
    articleContainers = renderArticles((ArrayList)map.get("articles"));
} else {
    f.removeComponent(mStateMachine.findExpertArticlesHeader(f));
    f.removeComponent(mStateMachine.findExpertArticlesContainer(f));
}
```

In `StateMachine`:

```
@Override
    protected void onDoctorDetails_ExpertTipsHeaderAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
        Container cnt = findExpertTipsContainer(c.getComponentForm());
        if(cnt.getComponentCount() > 0){
            cnt.removeAll();
        }else{
            for (int i = 0;i < expRenderer.tipContainers.length;i++){
                cnt.add(expRenderer.tipContainers[i]);
            }
            c.getComponentForm().scrollComponentToVisible(cnt);
        }

    }
```

**tl;dr**: It's a manual implementation of `Component.setHidden()`, which for some reason was not working well.  I create a bunch of `Container`s based on data I get from the server, stick them in an array, and when the button is clicked to show them, I iterate over the array and add the `Container`s (each one is essentially a list item) to a parent `Container`.

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

The UI hierarchy looks like this:

```
Form (BoxLayout Y)
  |
   - Container (FlowLayout)
  |
   - Container (TableLayout)
  |
   - Container (TableLayout)
  |
   - Button
  |
   - Label
  |
   - Button (populates following container)
  |
   - Container (BoxLayout Y - doesn't show lines)
  |
   - Button (populates following container)
  |
   - Container (BoxLayout Y - shows lines)
  |
   - Button (populates following container)
  |
   - Container (BoxLayout Y - shows lines)
```

The last three containers all have identical UIIDs, which derives from `Container` and modifies only the margins.  The difference is the containers being added to them.  To the first one I add a series of `SpanButton`s (and the lines don't appear).  To the other two I add a series of pre-assembled containers with a little content inside (and the lines appear).  The added containers in the latter case have the following style attributes:

`cn1-derive: Container;
margin: 0;
border-bottom: thin solid gray`

## Solution

The bottom border, which I defined in my css file, seemed to be causing the strange lines.  When I comment that line out, they disappear. Instead of being rendered only at the bottom of the container it was defined on, it was rendered all over the container.  This, I assume, is a bug.

Comment: Can you post the hierarchy you see in the designer and theme elements you use? Look at the theme itself does something have a background type defined within the hierarchy. You can also inspect the visual component hierarchy in the component inspector within the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `border-bottom` set on the containers I was adding in the code, defined in a css file.  It appears this triggered a bug that caused the border to render at even intervals all throughout the container, not just at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the GUI Builder to see that your containers UIID don't have a background image styling, and also your form.

Comment: Nope, no background on either one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you are seeing is the "line" entry from the code above. `setHidden()` only minimizes the space the component requests and doesn't actually hide it. Use `setVisible(false)` to truly hide the component.

Comment: I'm seeing the lines without using `setHidden()` or `setVisible()`.  `setVisible()` is equivalent to `display:none` in HTML, or does it still take up space?

Comment: Please see my answer - this is likely a bug in the css plugin.